# Javascript setInterval "catches up" after page is minimized / away

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a pretty normal `setInterval` call (I think):

```
var myInterval = setInterval("myFunction('passVar1', 'passedVar2')", 8000);
```

It runs perfectly if I'm on the page, but if I leave the page open for awhile (or minimize it?), when I come back, it's like it just built up all the myFunction calls into a queue and tries to run through them all really fast to "catch up".  Then, when it catches back up, it runs at 8 seconds apart again like it's supposed to.

Am I doing something wrong?  I'm using Firefox 5 at the moment - if that has anything to do with it.  Thoughts?  TIA.

Comment: Modern browsers do that on purpose. I think the idea is to reduce the system load imposed by non-focused tabs/windows, and then, when the window regains focus, they allow slowed interval timers to catch up.

Comment: @Pointy - that sucks.  Any way around it?  It looks very bad when the user comes back to my page, and it looks like it's tweaking out.  Clicking a button on the page to clear the interval doesn't even work - it still has to catch up before it clears it.

Comment: I agree, it causes all sorts of goofy effects.  The only thing I can imagine would be to have the interval-driven code explicitly check to see if it's running on schedule (by checking actual elapsed time).  It might even be easier/better to avoid interval timers altogether and do everything with "setTimeout()"; some people prefer that anyway as it's easier to control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For one thing fix your `setInterval` so it doesnt use eval:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
                     myFunction('passVar1', 'passedVar2')
                 }, 8000);
```

Second, it depends on the browser what the interval does or does not do.

---

UPDATE:

Based on comments below and the related chat discussion here is a fiddle using `setTimeout`:
http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/VR7WE/

---

UPDATE:

Based on further discussion, turns out it was an issue with jquery's animate

The following fiddle only runs the timeout when the animate is done: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/c869Z/5/

Comment: I'm setting my setInterval on page load - if I do what you're telling me to do, then function is run immediately, then 8 seconds later.  (not sure why, but it does).  If I run it using eval, it works as expected.  I'm glad to hear it's a browser thing, but - how can I fix it?  Is it possible to fix? / workaround?

Comment: @Dave, it will **not** be run immediately.  if you want to _fix it_ you might have to add on some handler to see when a user blurs the page and stop ur interval. it is always better to use this method for `setInterval` over the eval method

Comment: Also - on w3schools, it shows function calls in quotes like I'm using:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp (using eval as you put it)

Comment: @Dave -- http://w3fools.com/ -- w3schools cannot be trusted, dont go by their guidlines...

Comment: @Neal - it IS being run immediately when I do it your way.  It's not a question of whether I THINK it will - it is - I've just tested it.

Comment: @Dave let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/976/discussion-between-neal-and-dave)

Comment: I thought this was the answer, but unfortunately, using setTimeout as explained doesn't keep it from "tweaking out" when coming back to the page after a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can drive your own interval mechanism with "setTimeout()", and that will allow your code to adapt to the actual browser behavior. You'd probably do something to keep track of "target" times, and when you miss the target the next timeout would be correspondingly smaller than the nominal delay.  That way, even if your nominal delay was 100ms and the browser were only giving you control every 1000ms, you'd only have one pending timeout at any time. When focus returns, your code would then notice things getting back to normal and resume the higher-frequency activity pretty much automatically.

Comment: I tried setTimeout, but it's doing the same thing as setInterval did - since the timeout calls a function that then sets the timeout again.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm well I'd have to try it; I'll do a jsfiddle and see if I can make a simple setup work ...

Comment: OK [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4EGqt/) is a sample of what I was talking about.  When you first return to the page, one cycle will go too fast (with this particular implementation), but then it settles down. You could probably check for mouseover events to know when the window gets focus back, or something like that.